# Common property in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongoose, timestamp, schema

I am working on MongoDB and while writing the collections, I want to set a property in a collection to get 'When was the whole collection last updated' [NOT part of the schema]. Is there a way?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name : {type : String},
    email : {type : String, unique : true, trim : true,  sparse : true, index : true},
    phone : {type : String, required : true, unique : true },
    address : {type : String},
    dob : {type : String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

Thanks already!

Comment: Not sure if I userstand your meaning. Do you want to know when everything in the collection had an update applied to all documents, or do you just want to find the "most recent" updated time of any document in your collection. Also noting that you have not included any updated timestamp fields here.

Comment: Do you mean you wants the collection property which have updated Date ?

Comment: I want something like, if I make any CRUD operation in the Users DB, I want to know when was the last time any query was made related to the Users DB.

So There is no point of defining updated_at field in the schema.